# Back up Windows Shares with FreeNAS

Tags: backup, network-share, truenas

I need to create a backup 'server' in my company (about 12 PCs) where all have shared their 'data' directories.
So I was thinking to use my old PC with some HDD's and install FreeNAS on it but I have a little question - is it possible to do incremental backup from this shares? Or maybe you have another idea how to do this backup scenario.

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't use your old PC as a backup device. Backups are critical and you want to have a reliable system that works if you really need it. I also strongly suggest to keep your backup off-site for disaster recovery scenarios.

That said: FreeNAS offers ZFS snapshots. That's better then classic incremental backups.

Comment: In case you have more than 2 copies of data stored in different places, old PC may be good enough for the purpose. 3-2-1 rule all night long :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use old and reliable hardware while working with FreeNAS if you know how to build volumes to be resilient against HDD failures, otherwise, you are doomed no matter how reliable your server is. FreeNAS can easily import everything as long as you have all the HDDs, so even if your old PC fails, you can start a new FreeNAS server in minutes, connect your HDDs and import the volume back. 
regarding the incremental backups, it is covered by periodic snapshots, which you can make it happen every 5 minutes if you like.

Note: I recommend preparing another FreeNAS server and use replication feature just to have another copy if things went really bad.